# how to snapshot from component created with material ui styles in way that styles would be in snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-test-renderer

I am using [material-UI](https://material-ui.com/)  in my react web app. 
I want to test my component with jest  in way that styles would be saved in snapshot of component like what [jest-styled-component](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components) do for styled-component but I cant.

you can see my sample project in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1wq2ql2lv)
but here are the important parts:
I create my project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) with this command:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

this is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from './customTheme';
ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App/>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is my customTheme.js file in src folder:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: [
            'Roboto',
            '"Segoe UI"',
            '"Helvetica Neue"',
            'Arial',
            'sans-serif',
            '"Apple Color Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
        ].join(','),
    },
    palette: {
        color: 'blue',
    }
});
export default theme;
```

and this is my App.js that I want to test:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
export const styles = theme => ({
    mystyle: {
        fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily,
        border: '1px solid green',
        background: 'yellow',
        color: theme.palette.color,
    },
});
function MyComponent(props) {
    const {classes} = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <p className={classes.mystyle}> my text </p>
            <Button className={classes.mystyle}>my button</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

please notice that I am overwriting styles with JSS and I have my own theme.
I want to get snapshot from component in way that css be part of snapshot like [this issue from material-UI's repository in github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14357#issuecomment-470324935) or like what jest-styled-component-do for styled-component. for reaching that goal I wrote this code in my demo.test.js:

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import App from '../App';
import {styles} from '../App';
describe("snapshot test", () => {
    it("should match snapshot", () => {
        const wrapper = renderer
            .create(<App classes={styles}/>)
            .toJSON();
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

but with this test my styles are not in snapshot therefore if I change mystyle in App component the snapshot test will not fail.
I have read bellow resources but couldn't get what I wanted:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9492
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6834

thanks for any feedback

Comment: I would use Puppeteer for that task.
And I advise you not to use create-react-app for real application only for testing/tutorials etc.

Comment: @Arseniy-II That was my thought, too, but why is it a bad idea to continue using `create-react-app` for large scale apps?

Comment: Because tldr: it takes webpack control from you